# Wicket change label/textfield value

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, replace, label, wicket

I am trying to learn Wicket. One of the problems I encounter, is changing the values of components like a label.

This is how I declare the label:

```
Label message = new Label("message", new Model<String>(""));
message .setOutputMarkupId(true);
add(message );
```

The only solution I can find:

```
Label newMessage= new Label(message.getId(), "MESSAGE");
newMessage.setOutputMarkupId(true);
message.replaceWith(newMessage);
target.add(newMessage);
```

Is there a better/easier way to edit the value of a Wicket label and display this new value to the user?

Thanks!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I think you did not understand what Models are. Your example could be rewritten as follows

```
Model<String> strMdl = Model.of("My old message");
Label msg = new Label("label", strMdl);
msg.setOutputMarkupId(true);
add(msg);
```

In your ajax event

```
strMdl.setObject("My new message");
target.add(msg);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I did not understand them, but now I do. This is working perfectly